How can I make PrintWriter overwrite a specific line in a file?
I want to have an option in my program that allows the user to edit an existing file. But how can I tell PrintWriter the exact line I want to overwrite?
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class EditFiles
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String FileName;

   
      try
      {
         System.out.println("enter the name of the file: ");
         FileName = input.next() + ".txt";
         
         FileReader reader = new FileReader(FileName);
         Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(reader);
         for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
         {
            System.out.println(fileInput.next());
         }
      }
         
         catch (IOException e)
         {
            System.out.print(e);
         }
      }}     

This right here just shows the user what is in the file. It repeats 9 times because that's how many lines I need to be shown. I just want to be able to overwrite one of those nine.

You can't. You need to rewrite the file.

You can't unless you use a RandomAccessFile and the length of each line is fixed/known.

What camickr said.  "Lines" in a file aren't separate, they occur sequentially with the characters all packed together.  If one line changes length all of the other characters have to move up or down in the sequence or something won't be right.  As Mark mentions the most common way to deal with this is to just read the entire file, change it in memory, and then write the whole back to disc.

See this Answer using RandomFileAccess.

If the file is small enough to fit comfortably in memory Files.readAllLines would be your friend. Writer the List out again when editred
